# I'm getting Promise { <pennding> } on node.js async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have this function on a class on nodejs. It is getting all rows on DB.

```
module.exports = class fooClass {
  static async fooFunc() {
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const util = require('util');
    const conn = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
      database: 'dbname'
    });

    // node native promisify
    const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

    try {
      const rows = await query('SELECT * FROM `dbtable`');
      return rows;
    } finally {
      conn.end();
    }
  }
}
```

When I call this function,

```
let result = fooClass.fooFunc();
console.log(result);
```

I am getting this:

```
Promise { <pennding> }
```

I can use `fooClass.fooFunc().then...` but that will require me to add a callback function on `then` and that will require a lot of changes.

Is there any way we can get the rows by just calling `let result = fooClass.fooFunc();`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, async functions return a Promise ... accessing resolved Promise values requires async/await or .then - there is no way to get a synchronous result when dealing with asynchrony - because asynchronous results are resolved at "some time in the future", nothing can be used to *predict* when (which you would need to make asynchronous results synchronous)

Comment: @Bravo So is there any way we can just `let result = fooClass.fooFunc();` and get the rows?

Comment: `let result = await fooClass.fooFunc();` - a long as that statement is inside a `async function` - but then, whatever calls that function would either have to use async/await or promise.then ... and then if you need to wait for that function to finish, you again, need to use async/await or promise.then ... see how no matter how deep you go with functions, you can never overcome asynchrony - because "some time in the future" persists up the call chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When function call is done within a function then you can write it as @Bravo has suggested:

```
let result = await fooClass.fooFunc();
```

Link for [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

If you are calling it outside a function then :

```
(async function(){
   let result = await fooClass.fooFunc();
})();
```